# jQuery resizable button to diagonal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, resize

i want input a button in div, when i over on button the mouse cursor turns into the shape of diagonal resize and the user can do this action.

This is because the users find it difficult put the mouse at the exact position of diagonal resize.

Thanks

Comment: does it looks like this kind of stuff ? http://jsfiddle.net/byLj4q1d/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish without any code.  But something like this can get you started:

```
<script>
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100px',
            height: '30px'
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    #Button1 {
        cursor: nesw-resize;
    }
</style>
```